# R: extraer un fichero mediante predicciones ranger

Tags: r

He usado el paquete ranger (equivalente a Random Forest) para hacer un árbol de decisión. El resultado son una serie de predicciones con valor 0 (unidad no válida según la decisión del árbol) y 1 (unidad válida).
¿Cómo creo un nuevo fichero en el que estén solo las válidas?

```
objeto1 <- ranger(variable_dependiente ~ variable_explicativa_1 + variable_explicativa_2, 
                 data = datos.entrenamiento) #Construcción del árbol solo para los datos de entrenamiento
objeto2 <- predict(objeto1, data = datos.test) #Aplicación de lo que ha aprendido en el entrenamiento
print(objeto2$predictions)
```

El resultado de ese print es: 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1, etc
Quiero crear un nuevo data frame con las unidades cuyo valor es 1 en este print.

Comment: A menos que te interprete mal, entiendo que así `objeto2[objeto2$predictions==1, ]`

Comment: Me dice que el número de dimensiones es incorrecto

Comment: Es cierto, mala mía, `predict()` no entrega un data.frame, prueba con  `datos.test[objeto2$predictions==1, ]`

Comment: ¿Ahora como compruebo que mi nuevo archivo es correcto? Porque la primera columna de numeración me dice que el primero se corresponde con el 17, después 21... Sin embargo mi primer 1 es la tercera unidad (en print objeto2$predictions)